# Escape sequence of javascript in php

Tags: javascript

Below code is not working , I have escaped single quote and double quote with slash but I get error " unterminated string literal" in firebug.

```
 echo '
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
switch (keyChar) {       
    case "\"":
    case "\'":
        animateKey(40);
        break;

}
}';
```

Comment: There's no PHP in there so why bother using `echo` at all?

Comment: thanks it working now , i have put the javascript code out side php tags .

Answer (score 0):

The backslash in the PHP string is actually still functioning as an escape sequence, so no backslashes will be emitted in the resulting HTML. You'll need to escape the slash as well:

```
echo '
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
    switch (keyChar) {       
        case "\\"":
        case "\'":
            animateKey(40);
            break;
    }
}';
```

You can also use a HEREDOC, even better, a [NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to reduce the need for escaping.

```
echo <<<'EOT'
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
    switch (keyChar) {       
        case '"':
        case "'":
            animateKey(40);
            break;
    }
}
EOT;
```

Alternatively, if this is just static HTML, why emit it with PHP at all? Just put it outside the `<?php ?>` tags as ordinary markup.

```
<?php
// code
?>
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
    switch (keyChar) {       
        case '"':
        case "'":
            animateKey(40);
            break;
    }
}
<?php
// more code
?>
```

Comment: @Phil Yes, yes I do. I apologize if it looks like I "plagiarized" from your answer—I assure you I was typing this out concurrently. But, you know, the [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: The thing is, your original answer did not switch the quotes around in the case statements (you opted to escape them) yet your edit takes a departure from this

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** build this string in PHP, I'd recommend HEREDOC

```
$js = <<<_JS
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
    switch (keyChar) {       
        case '"':
        case "'":
            animateKey(40);
            break;
        }
}
_JS;
echo $js;
```

Alternatively, just drop out of PHP entirely

```
?>
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
    switch (keyChar) {       
        case '"':
        case "'":
            animateKey(40);
            break;
        }
}
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this in Javascript :

```
function AnimateButtonPress(keyChar) {
switch (keyChar) {       
    case """:
    case "'":
        animateKey(40);
        break;
}}
```

which is not valid JS. You have to escape the quotes twice, once for php and once for Javascript.

```
case "\\\"":
case "\'":
```